# Adding right brace and equation number

Tags: equations, numbering, braces

I have an eqnarray that consists of 4 lines. I would like to have a right brace } that spans the last two lines with equation number, first equation with equation number and second equation with nonumber. Some brief text explaining these two parts of the equation. Something like

```
a=b   (1)
c=d
x=y}
   }  (2) 
z=t}
```

Comment: could you use align for equations?

Comment: yes I could use align

Comment: Do all four equations have to be aligned at the equal sign?

Comment: yes. They have to be aligned at the equal sign? I forgot to write. Thanks

Comment: potential duplicate: [Combining split and rcases](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66615/579)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick solution. It uses a manually set size of the brace. Maybe someone can provide something more robust.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
a &{} = b \\
c &{} = d \nonumber \\
\begin{split}
    x &{} = y \\
    z &{} = t
\end{split} \quad \bigg \rbrace \quad \text{comment text}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick solution. It is useful for me. But I wonder how can provide without setting size of the brace.